# Monitoring failed ssh logins with pam and bash?

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-14.04, pam

I modified /etc/pam.d/common-auth to run a bash script when a login fails or when a login is successful and it works for successful logins but not failed login attempts when trying to ssh. Once I am already on the server and try use sudo both scripts will run for both failed authentication and success. Why won't login-failed-notify.sh excecute during a failed ssh login attempt? I added the following to the default /etc/pam.d/common-auth file.

```
# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
auth    [success=2 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
auth optional pam_exec.so seteuid /etc/ssh/failed-login-notify.sh
auth    requisite                       pam_deny.so
auth optional pam_exec.so seteuid /etc/ssh/login-notify.sh
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
auth    required                        pam_permit.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
auth    optional                        pam_cap.so
# end of pam-auth-update config
```

My bash scripts have no logic, they simply send a get request when they are run.

Here is my login-notify.sh, failed-login-notify.sh is exactly the same but says failed in the text.

```
#!/bin/sh
CURL='/usr/bin/curl'
RVMHTTP="http://192.168.1.100/update.php?ip=$PAM_HOST&server=192.168.1.101&status=success"
CURLARGS="-f -s -S -k"
raw="$($CURL $CURLARGS $RVMHTTP)"
```

Here is /etc/pam.d/sshd

```
# PAM configuration for the Secure Shell service

# Standard Un*x authentication.
@include common-auth

# Disallow non-root logins when /etc/nologin exists.
account required        pam_nologin.so

# Uncomment and edit /etc/security/access.conf if you need to set complex
# access limits that are hard to express in sshd_config.
# account  required     pam_access.so

# Standard Un*x authorization.
@include common-account

# SELinux needs to be the first session rule.  This ensures that any
# lingering context has been cleared.  Without this it is possible that a
# module could execute code in the wrong domain.
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad]        pam_selinux.so close

# Set the loginuid process attribute.
session required        pam_loginuid.so

# Create a new session keyring.
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke

# Standard Un*x session setup and teardown.
@include common-session

# Print the message of the day upon successful login.
# This includes a dynamically generated part from /run/motd.dynamic
# and a static (admin-editable) part from /etc/motd.
session    optional     pam_motd.so  motd=/run/motd.dynamic noupdate
session    optional     pam_motd.so # [1]

# Print the status of the user's mailbox upon successful login.
session    optional     pam_mail.so standard noenv # [1]

# Set up user limits from /etc/security/limits.conf.
session required        pam_limits.so

# Read environment variables from /etc/environment and
# /etc/security/pam_env.conf.
session required        pam_env.so
# In Debian 4.0 (etch), locale-related environment variables were moved to
# /etc/default/locale, so read that as well.
session required        pam_env.so      user_readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale

# SELinux needs to intervene at login time to ensure that the process starts
# in the proper default security context.  Only sessions which are intended
# to run in the user's context should be run after this.
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad]        pam_selinux.so open

# Standard Un*x password updating.
@include common-password
```

Comment: Please share all of the lines in the `auth` stack. It makes no sense that `failed-login-notify.sh` is firing on successful authentication

Comment: Sorry if that was unclear, I have another file called login-notify.sh that fires on successful authentication. failed-login-notify.sh is only firing when trying to use sudo and typing the wrong password but login-notify.sh will fire when logging in via ssh and using sudo

Comment: Thanks. To confirm though, there are no `auth` lines above this? I need the whole picture.

Comment: Sorry, added all the lines in the file to make it clearer.

Comment: Thanks. No line skips in `/etc/pam.d/sshd` either? (success=N)

Comment: No, all I have in there is success=ok

Comment: I think you're going to need to share the contents of the script. Either the script contents are directly relevant, there is a line skip (which you've checked for), or you're hitting the equivalent of a `sufficient` in `/etc/pam.d/sshd`. May as well share the contents of `sshd` too while you're at it, the comments have already gotten long.

Comment: Question has been updated with both files. Should have been included from the beginning. Thanks!